# ListView Itemsource not showing object Xamarin Forms

Tags: listview, mvvm, xamarin.forms, data-binding

This list view is just not cooperating with me. I'm trying to display some hours that comes from service.
Please see the following screenshot
1. I got a list of Items 
[image]

2. Inside those Items, I need Time list
   [image]

3.Xaml looks like this - Note = I tried {Binding Time}

```
 <ListView x:Name="HoursList" ItemsSource="{Binding PIEItems}"
                         CachingStrategy ="RecycleElement"
                         Grid.Row="2" 
                         Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                         HasUnevenRows="True"
                         SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                         SeparatorColor="Navy">
                   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                          <ViewCell>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Times}"></Label>
                          </ViewCell>
                      </DataTemplate>
                   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
               </ListView>
```

3.View Model

```
ObservableCollection<DaysFormatting> _pieitems;
      public ObservableCollection<DaysFormatting> PIEItems
      {
         get
         {
            return _pieitems;
         }
         set
         {
            if (_pieitems != value)
            {
               _pieitems = value;
               PropertyChanged?.Invoke(
                   this,
                   new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(PIEItems)));
            }
         }

      }
```

//on method => EDIT

```
public void GetTimer()
      {
        if (a == c)
            {

               List<AvailableHrs> lsthrs = await data.GeteTimes(c, serviceId);
               ChosenDates.Time = new List<string>();
               foreach (var hr in lsthrs)
               {
                  ChosenDates.horas = hr.time;
                  Debug.WriteLine("to be ...." + ChosenDates.horas);
                  ChosenDates.Time.Add(hr.time);

                  Debug.WriteLine("to be in binding" + ChosenDates.Time);
               }

            }

            AvailableDates.Add(ChosenDates);

         }

         PIEItems = new ObservableCollection<DaysFormatting>(AvailableDates);
       }
```

Comment: Label displays a string.  You need to bind to a property on your object that returns a string.  `"{Binding .}"` is `DaysFormatting` and `"{Binding Time}"` is an `IEnumerable` neither of which are string.

Comment: @Jason can you share a snippet? please

Comment: You need to clarify what your problem is.   @Roubachof is correct that your ItemsSource is not setup properly either.  You need to fix that before you fix the binding of your Label

Comment: I added the method that gets the data and I fixed the typo with the items source binding.  Please let me know

Comment: have you set the BindingContext for you page?  Is your LIstView showing any rows?  Try hard coding the value of Label in your template to check.

Comment: Could you please explain the meaning of several structures in your code,eg. `AvailableDates`, `DaysFormatting`? It's probably best to post the code of the models you're using.

Answer (score 1):

since you're trying to access the property Times inside PIEItems, you need to bind your list view like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="HoursList" ItemsSource="{Binding PIEItems.Times}">
```

And access to its props like this:

```
 <ListView x:Name="HoursList" ItemsSource="{Binding PIEItems.Times}"
                     CachingStrategy ="RecycleElement"
                     Grid.Row="2" 
                     Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                     HasUnevenRows="True"
                     SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                     SeparatorColor="Navy">
               <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Capacity}"></Label>
                      </ViewCell>
                  </DataTemplate>
               </ListView.ItemTemplate>
           </ListView>
```

Hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You're binding to the wrong property:

change

```
<ListView x:Name="HoursList" BindingContext="'PIEItems"
```

to

```
<ListView x:Name="HoursList" ItemsSource="{Binding PIEItems}"
```